# How can I style an IFRAME element that has a constantly changing class name?

Tags: css, embed

On my blog, the Pinterest button creates a small gap underneath the footer. Looking at the code, the cause is the iFrame that the Pinterest javascript embeds in the page. It looks like this:

```
<iframe src="//assets.pinterest.com/pidget.html?r=862117.4577227819#via=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Finternet-security%2F&amp;type=pidget" height="0" width="0" frameborder="0" class="PIN_1361148986939_log"></iframe>
```

I can use Chrome's dev tools to apply display: none; to it, but here's the problem: The class changes every time you load the page.

Is there a way to targe this specific iFrame in CSS without using the class name?

Comment: What if you wrap iframe with html element e.g. div or span and give a specific name to it e.g. `class="pinterestBug87315"` and then in your css you will be able to do following `.pinterestBug87315 iframe { diplay: none; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select every iframe, just by writing:

```
iframe{display:none}
```

If you have multiple iframes, and this is the only one you want to apply this styling to, you can write something like this:

```
iframe[src^="//assets.pinterest.com/pidget.html"]{display:none}
```

Note: Not really a WordPress question, but pure CSS related.

Comment: Thanks - worked like a charm! Sorry I put this in the wrong forum.